# Connect Python with Flutter for a web based solution

Tags: flutter

Is it a good idea or possible to connect a python backend to a flutter frontend?

I want to develop an employee scheduling app. The user should save shifts and employee availability within the app.

These data should then be read within python and optimal shifts should get suggested and send back to the flutter frontend.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Flutter is your **technology for creating UIs**, you can connect it to whatever you want; including connecting to some API using HTTP and the API also can be written in Python as well as Dart, PHP, Java, C++ or whatever other language that handles HTTP requests.

It doesn't really matter what you're using on a backend, as long as you (or your team) are comfortable with given technology at and it's performant enough (which isn't an issue in a majority of cases).